# Passing an iterator

Tags: iterators

The code

```
Table[i, {i, 5}]
```

produces the output

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

whereas the code

```
x = {i, 5};
Table[i, x];
```

produces an error, namely

```
Table::itform: Argument x at position 2 does not have the correct form for an iterator.
```

Why, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Try this, `Table@@{i,x}`. If you check the `Attributes` of `Table` you will notice that has the `HoldAll` attribute so the `x` will not be evaluated.

Comment: You can also say `Table[i,x//Evaluate]` but I find it a little ugly :P

Comment: Try `With[{x = {i, 5}}, Table[i, x]]`.

Comment: I would like to petition that this question be un- marked as duplicate.

This question is REALLY about how you pass an entire iterator form as a value to a function.

The other question is about getting a built in function to correctly handle a new, user-specified iterator form.

They are just superficially similar in that they both (incidentally) use the iterator argument to `Table` as an example problem for the actual underlying question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Table` has attribute `HoldAll`. This means its arguments are left unevaluated:

```
Attributes[Table]
(* {HoldAll, Protected} *)
```

Using an `Evaluate` will force the evaluation order to be as you desire:

```
x = {i, 5};
Table[i, Evaluate@x]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```